# Python: os.system x actual command

Tags: python, operating-system, ubuntu-14.04

When I execute the command below directly through the command line, it works properly:

```
mpg321 -a bluetooth Canon.mp3
```

However, by executing the code below via Python:

```
import os
os.system('mpg321 -a bluetooth Canon.mp3')
```

I get the following error:

> ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluetooth
>   Can't open libao driver with device bluetooth (is device in use?)

Any idea what might be wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: This might be because the user who is running `os.system(...)` does not have privileges to write to /dev/audio. See [the Debian SoundFAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/SoundFAQ) (search for "Can't open libao") which points to https://wiki.debian.org/SoundConfiguration for the solution.

Comment: Great idea. os.system('sudo -u pi mpg321 -a bluetooth Canon.mp3') solved the issue! Thanks! Please post the answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mpg321 error message :

> Can't open libao driver

may occur if the user does not have privileges to write to /dev/audio.  See the
[Debian SoundFAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/SoundFAQ) (search for "Can't open
libao") which points to http://wiki.debian.org/SoundConfiguration for the
solution, namely, to add the user to the `audio` group.

```
adduser USER_NAME audio
```

Or, do as the OP did and run the command as a user who already has the correct privileges.